# image isn't saving into db in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m  trying to save data into db data saves but image isn't saving how to save it in db:

controller:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    $request->validate([
        'category_name'         => 'required',
        'category_description'  => 'required',
        'category_slug'         => 'required',
        'category_image'        => 'required|image',
    ]);

    DB::table('categories')->insert([
        'category_name'          => $request->category_name,
        'category_description'   => $request->category_description,
        'category_slug'          => $request->category_slug,
        'category_image'         => $request->category_image,
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('category_image');
    $path->getClientOriginalName();
    $path->move(public_path('images/backend_images/category_images');

    return back();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to store the entire file in the database, and then also in the file system.  Ideally, you would just store the **path** to the file in the database.

Comment: only name of file stores into db, my code is wrong so i post it here to resolve it,,,, now it says: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' at this line:: $path->move(public_path('images/backend_images/category_images');    can u tell me how to solve it

Comment: It's missing another `)` before the `;`.

Comment: now whole data isn't saving and not giving any error

Answer (score 0):

Well... In your portion of code, there is no `var.save();` so how will eloquent store any data without the given instruction?

Per example do something like this:

```
$userImage = new UserImage;
$UserImage->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    $request->validate([
        'category_name'         => 'required',
        'category_description'  => 'required',
        'category_slug'         => 'required',
        'category_image'        => 'required|image',
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('category_image');
    $nameImage = $path->getClientOriginalName();
    $path->move(base_path('public/images/backend_images/category_images'), $nameImage);

    DB::table('categories')->insert([
        'category_name'          => $request->category_name,
        'category_description'   => $request->category_description,
        'category_slug'          => $request->category_slug,
        'category_image'         => $nameImage,
    ]);


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

code in my project and its work!

```
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image'); 
        $filename     = date('mdYHis') .str_random(5).'.'.$file->extension();
        $request->image->move(base_path('public/images/rooms'), $filename);
        $request->merge(array('image' => $filename));;
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` after `$nameImage)` and they are saving to `public_path` not `base_path`.

Comment: @matticustard i edited i used base_path and its saved in public folder!

Comment: now whole data isn't saving and not giving any error

Comment: No, `base_path('images/` is not the public folder.  That would be `base_path('public/images/`.

Comment: Also, you're only storing the filename, not the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help. But you can browse for more answers.

Save to **public directory**

```
$path = 'images/backend_images/category_images';
$file = $request->file('category_image');
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move(public_path($path), $filename);
```

And the, save to **database**

```
DB::table('categories')->insert([
    'category_name'          => $request->category_name,
    'category_description'   => $request->category_description,
    'category_slug'          => $request->category_slug,
    'category_image'         => $filename
]);
```